# Complex Table Join (Doctrine ORM)

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I have the following Table structure to like posted Activities (Facebook Like function):

**User:** id, firstname, lastname

**KickPointAction:** id, user_id, post_id, timestamp

**Post:** id, user_id, text, timestamp

If someone likes a Post, an entry with a reference to the target post will be created in the KickPointAction. I need to get a leaderboard now to count how many likes the users have.

This is the current Code, but :

```
        $allUsers = $this->getObjectManager()->getRepository('Db\Entity\User')->findAll();
    $usersArray = array();
    foreach($allUsers as $user) {
        $usersArray[] = $this->getObjectManager()->createQueryBuilder()
            ->select('u.firstname, u.lastname, u.id AS userid, u.avatarUri, COUNT(u) AS total_kickpoints')
            ->from('Db\Entity\User', 'u')
            ->innerJoin(
                'Db\Entity\Post',
                'p',
                Join::WITH,
                'u.id= p.user'
            )
            ->innerJoin(
                'Db\Entity\KickPointToPost',
                'k',
                Join::WITH,
                'k.post=p.id'
            )
            ->andwhere('p.user = :user')
            ->setParameter('user', $user)
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult()[0];
    }
```

I think this is not the best way to get the Leaderboard. Is there any other solution available, maybe with a right join beginning from the Users table?